# How do I exclude a sub folder/directory from the Azure Backup for an App Service?

Tags: powershell, azure, backup, azure-web-app-service, kudu

How do I exclude a sub folder/directory from the Azure Backup for an App Service?

Our backup system seems to fail because this folder makes the site exceed the backup limit. So I'd like to exclude only that folder.

> The website + database size exceeds the 10 GB limit for backups. Your
>   content size is 10 GB.

Comment: What script are you using to perform the backup? Edit your question and post the code.

Answer (score 1):

@AjayKumar-MSFT's link to [Partial Backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup#configure-partial-backups) works, but here's the details:

- create a file called _backup.filter
- list one directory or file per line
- Upload _backup.filter file to the D:\home\site\wwwroot\ directory of your site

Example:

```
   \site\wwwroot\Images\brand.png
   \site\wwwroot\Images\2014
   \site\wwwroot\Images\2013
```

Answer (score 0):

You may filter out unnecessary files from the backup by Configuring Partial Backups. You can exclude static content that does not often change such as videos/images or unneeded log files (directories). 
[Partial backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-backup#configure-partial-backups) allow you to choose exactly which files you want to backup.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you could check your app usage(Make sure your web app has already use 10GB). You can determine folder content size using the Azure Web Apps Disk Usage Site Extension.

You could follow this steps to see the disk usage:

- Browse the Kudu site for your web app: https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net Click on Site extensions and then click on Gallery.
- Search for Azure Web Apps Disk Usage site extension. Click on + icon to install the site extension.
- Click run to start the Disk Usage Site Extension

If your web site is not exceed the 10GB. I suggest you could create a new service plan and move the your web app to the new service plan and test again. Maybe something wrong with the web app server.

If this still doesn't solve your issue. You don't exceed the 10GB but still show this error. I suggest you could create an [Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

> How do I exclude a sub folder/directory from the Azure Backup for an App Service?

As Ajay says, you could use [Partial backups](http://zainrizvi.io/2015/06/05/creating-partial-backups-of-your-site-with-azure-web-apps/).